# Following a rigging Tutorial and got this error (bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones)

Tags: rigging

I have been working on a model as a learning tool and by following a tutorial. It seems like I can't set automatic weights for my rig. I tried removing doubles, also removing and resetting my rig, but still nothing helped. Can someone point out what I missed?

I'm still trying to figure out how to upload my file for test cases.

[image]

Comment: File upload at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Here is my model I'm working on hope this helps

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3636" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3636/)